# Why I am getting an error that no member show is declared in the class, whereas it is declared in the class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

> class "bankdeposit" has no member "show"

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
    
using namespace std;
    
class bankdeposit
{
    int principal, years;
    float interest, returnvalue;
    
public:
    bankdeposit(){};
    bankdeposit(int p, int y, float r); // can be 2.00
    bankdeposit(int p, int y, int r);   // can be 2.
};
    
bankdeposit::bankdeposit(int p, int y, float r)
{
    principal = p;
    years = y;
    interest = r;
    returnvalue = principal;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        returnvalue = returnvalue * (1 + r);
    }
};
    
bankdeposit::bankdeposit(int p, int y, int r)
{
    principal = p;
    years = y;
    interest = float(r) / 100; 
    returnvalue = principal;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        returnvalue = returnvalue * (1 + r);
    }
    void show();
};
    
void bankdeposit::show(){
   
}
    
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code in a more readable.

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags. C and C++ are very different languages.

Comment: You didn't declare `void show();` in the class `bankdeposit`; you declared it in the constructor body.

Comment: presumably declined is actually declared - please post error messages using copy and paste

Comment: @fabian thanx, solved, i haven't checked the brackets 30 mins wasted successfully 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `bankdeposit(int, int, int)` constructor, the expression `void show();` is in the wrong place.  It needs to be inside the `bankdeposit` class declaration instead:

```
class bankdeposit
{
    ...    
public:
    ...
    void show(); // <-- move to here
};

bankdeposit::bankdeposit(int p, int y, int r)
{
    ...
    // void show(); // <-- remove from here
};
```

---

On a site note, your default `bankdeposit()` constructor is not initializing any of the class data members, so their values will be indeterminate.  Either remove that constructor, or give the data members default values.